# Return Lowest Value from a List [R]

Tags: r, list

How can I find the lowest value from a list?

I know `min()` works with vectors

```
v <- c(1,2,7,0,45,78,89,90,2,-1)
min(v)
> -1
```

but it does not work with lists.

```
l <- list(1,2,7,0,45,78,89,90,2,-1)
min(l)
> Error in min(c) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
min( unlist( list(1,2,7,0,45,78,89,90,2,-1) ) )
```

Comment: better still:

    sapply(l, min)

Comment: That doesn't work for me; it just spits out the list again.

Comment: you have to put vector in the list as a vector, not as a many-component list...l <- c(number, number, number)...then sapply(l, min)

Answer (score 5):

There is also `Reduce` for this case:

```
Reduce(min, l)
# [1] -1
```

It will also work if the list elements are not all length 1:

```
l2 <- list(a = c(1,-2), 2,7,0,45,78,89,90,2,-1)
Reduce(min, l)
# [1] -2
```